# MongoDB multi-tenant design faces unexpected slow insertion time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have been working on a multi-tenant model for our business and using MongoDB for handling the data for our clients,  our clients are basically some organizations that have their our users using the system.

Now we have a single application layer (single application deployment) for controlling or connecting to multiple databases within a single cluster. The change of database connection happens in the application (Built with Node.js and Mongoose) layer. Each database contains the same collections, for example db-00 and db-01 will have the same number of collections such as users, business_units, bookings, doucment_management, inventories... etc.

For each request entering the server the following code executes to connect the user request to the appropriate dataase:

```
const MONGO_URI = < only the cluster url with user and password no /db attached here >
let databaseCluster = {};
const connect = (db) => {
  mongoose.plugin(forceRunValidators);
  return mongoose.createConnection(
    process.env.MONGO_URI + `/${db}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      autoIndex: true,
    }
  );
};

// this function si called once the server starts in the server js file
exports.connectToCluster = () =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let adminConnection = await connect(process.env.ADMIN_DB);
      let tenants = await Tetants(adminConnection).find({});
      databaseCluster = adminConnection;
      console.log("MongoDB admin Connected");
      tenantsMap = tenants;
      resolve("Tenants cached successfully.");
      console.log("Tenants cached successfully");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      reject(err);
      // Exit process with failure
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });

exports.getConnectionByTenant = (tenantName) => {
  let connection = null;
  connection = databaseCluster.useDb(tenantName, { useCache: true });
  return connection;
};
```

Whenever a model is compiled an example code looks like this:

```
const connection = getConnectionByTenant("my_tenant");
const ModelBuilder = (connection) => connection.model("collection_name",modelSchema);
const Model = ModelBuilder(connection);
```

Finally in the data access layer it is used as normal code as following:

```
// insert operation
const DataObject = new Model({
  property_1:"some_value",
  ...
}) 
await dataObject.save();

// find operation
const data = await Model.findOne({});
```

The system works fine locally and Atlas cluster as well. It connects to different databases as expected. But we have come across a wired  problem.

**Problem statement**

When inserting data only a single database becomes really slow, for example consider we have **db_1**, **db_2**, **db_3**  insert  operation becomes really slow in **db_3** even though there is almost no data and takes about 40 seconds to insert an item.  And when we restart the server the problem shifts to a different database like **db_2** and **db_3** becomes normal. We have confirmed that this problem occurs on one database only doesn't matter how may db we have. Except for the particular db all other dbs operate perfectly fine.

**Invesigations**

I have tried to monitor the insert operation in mongodb shell as well, with following commands but results are not very useful.

```
db.currentOp({
  "op": "insert"
}, true);
```

It always returns `inprog` as an empty array.

```
{ inprog: [],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': 
   { clusterTime: Timestamp(1, 1700042646),
     signature: 
      { hash: BinData(0, "z5Pv/28gd21JtFpYB0bpQBk+NTc="),
        keyId: NumberLong("7244587175163985926") } },
  operationTime: Timestamp(1, 1700042646) }
```

Could anyone help on this issue.

Reyad

Answer (score 0):

I think problem come from `useDb`. useDb will switch to a different database using the same connection pool. The problem is here when you dont config connection pool, it default is `5` and your request need to save to many collection from many database caused slow by switch and over 5 conn.

It would better for create different connection to another database.

```
function makeNewConnection(uri) {
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 300000
    });

    db.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connection ${this.name} ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        db.close().catch(() => console.log(`MongoDB :: failed to close connection ${this.name}`));
    });

    db.on('connected', function () {
        mongoose.set('debug', function (col, method, query, doc) {
            console.log(`MongoDB :: ${this.conn.name} ${col}.${method}(${JSON.stringify(query)},${JSON.stringify(doc)})`);
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connected ${this.name}`);
    });

    db.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: disconnected ${this.name}`);
    });

    return db;
}

const connection1 = makeNewConnection(mongoConfig.uriConnection1);
const connection2 = makeNewConnection(mongoConfig.uriConnection2);
```

Comment: I understand your solution but wouldn't it be overwhelming for the server if there is 1000 database? How would the memory look like cause from this it looks like I have to save my DBs in an object and access them like `dbconnections.dbconn_1`? And will MongoDB accept these much connections because from the documentation it looks like connections are limited to 1500 only for a M10 cluster.

Comment: if you heavy insert document to 1000 database (not find or findAndUpdate),  it is IOPS bound so the memory isn't the problem. About connection, you must use `database connection singleton` to avoid leak connection by creating object model